# Calling a templated method allowing only subclasses as parameter

Tags: c++, templates, specialization

Suppose I have set of classes inheriting from a single superclass S:

```
class S{ ... };

class C1 : public S{ ... };
class C2 : public S{ ... };
```

Then suppose I have a templated method:

```
template<class T> void foo(T* instance);
```

I would like to statically check that foo is never called providing an instance of the superclass but only called providing one of the (concrete) subclasses (e.g. explicitly calling `foo<C1>(x)` for instance)

Is this possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First we can write a trait to check if `T` is derived from `S`, but not `S`:

```
template <class Base, class Derived>
using is_strict_base = 
    std::integral_constant<bool,
        std::is_base_of<Base,Derived>::value && 
        !std::is_same<Base,typename std::remove_cv<Derived>::type>::value>;
```

You can use `std::enable_if` to use this trait:

```
template<class T>
typename std::enable_if<is_strict_base<S,T>::value>::type
foo(T* instance)
{}
```

With C++14 you can use `std::enable_if_t` to make it a bit prettier:

```
template<class T>
std::enable_if_t<is_strict_base<S,T>::value>
foo(T* instance)
{}
```

Another option is to use `static_assert`:

```
template<class T>
void foo(T* instance)
{
    static_assert(is_strict_base<S,T>::value, 
                  "T must be derived from S, but not S");
}
```

This gives you a nicer error, but I personally believe that type constraints for a function belong in the declaration.